# I don't know how to use vnc2flv

Tags: windows, vnc

I want to record the screen with a vnc server. I know it is possible using Vnc2flv, but I don't understand how. Can help me with a simple tutorial?

in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpted from [Softpedia](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Vnc2flv-48834.shtml):

> **How to Use**
>
> Currently, there is only one command, flvrec.py.
>
> flvrec.py
>
> flvrec.py is the main recording program. It connects the specified VNC
>   server and immediately starts recording when it's started and stops
>   when Ctrl-C is pressed (or SIGINT is sent to the process). You need to
>   have a VNC server running on the target machine in advance.
>
> The recorded file is playable via either desktop programs like ffmpeg,
>   VLC or mplayer, or a bunch of online Flash-based players.
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
> flvrec.py [options] [host[:port]]
> ```
>
> **Examples:**
>
> $ x11vnc -quiet -localhost -viewonly -nopw -bg  (start up a vnc
>   server)
>
> The VNC desktop is: localhost:0  PORT=5900
>
> $ flvrec.py localhost:5900  (Record a local desktop)
>
> $ flvrec.py -W 640x480 localhost:5900  (Record a local desktop with a
>   640x480 window that tracks the changes automatically.)
>
> $ flvrec.py remotehost:5900  (Connect a remote computer and record
>   its screen)
>
> **Options:**
>
> ```
> -o filename  Specifies the output file name.
> -P pwdfile  Specifies the password file for a vnc session.
> -C wxh+x+y  Specifies the clipping.
> -W wxh  Specifies the auto scrolling.
> -N  Suppress cursor display.
> -e encoding,encoding,...  Specifies the vnc encoding methods.
> -d  Increases the debug level.
> ```